# Monitoring changes in web page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that is separated into "sections" that are accessible by a tabbed format (tabbable tabs-left).

I would like to be able to have the tab change text color if any item in that tab has changed.

I'm using bootstrap framework and jQuery.

Not all fields are text, some are radio and some are selects.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a custom event and triggering it with the change events of all textareas, selects, and inputs in the tab.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.tab').bind( "tabedited", function(){
        alert("Content edited");
  });

  $('input, textarea, select').change(function () {
      $(this).parent().trigger('tabedited');
  });
});​
```

Comment: While the "tabedited" function was actually not needed, the other led me to what I needed.

Comment: `$("input, textarea, select").bind("keyup change input", function ()`